# Central force problem, Bertrand's theorem

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, symmetry

How can you explain the statement that "the only central forces that result in closed orbits for all bound particles are the inverse square law and Hooke's law."

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/578932/2451

Comment: Hi R-azz Bhandari. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.